# aws ec2 revoke-security-group-ingress not deleting rules

Tags: amazon-web-services, console, aws-cli

I am trying to delete all rules of a certain group which allow access on port 22 with the following command.

`aws ec2 revoke-security-group-ingress --group-name mygroupname --protocol tcp --port 22`

Though this isn't deleting any rules.
When I specify a cidr (--cidr) of any specific rule it deletes the rule but I want to apply it to every possible cidr. How can I achieve that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Probably you have to use [describe-security-group-rules](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/describe-security-group-rules.html) to get the detailed list of the rules in your SG, and then iterate over that list and delete the rules matching your crtiera.